# Matplotlib not showing full date on np.datetime64 x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data with a `datetime64` x-axis:

```
t = np.arange(np.datetime64('2022-07-19T12:00:00.00'), np.datetime64('2022-07-19T15:00:00.00'), np.timedelta64(1, 'h'))
y = np.random.rand(3)
plt.plot(t, y)
```

[image]

The x-axis shows day, hour, minute. I am not looking to get the high-resolution values (sec, ms), but I would like to see at least the month, and possibly the year. I don't mind if it's an offset on the bottom right corner of the plot.

How do I display the x-axis data with month and year information?

Comment: I think you will have to set a manual date formatter.  Like in this example in the docs  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Comment: Please see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/date_concise_formatter.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak. Yup. Ended up using that with all default settings. It worked perfectly. Please feel free to add an answer for me to accept

Comment: @AeroEngy. You led me to the right answer. If you post it here, I will have something to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Matplotlib documentation there is an example of setting date tick labels using the default, concise, and manual date formatter.  I suspect you will need to setup a manual formatter with your specific options.

[Date Tick Label Example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html#date-tick-labels)

Copy pasting the example here but see the link/docs for more information:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

# Load a numpy structured array from yahoo csv data with fields date, open,
# close, volume, adj_close from the mpl-data/example directory.  This array
# stores the date as an np.datetime64 with a day unit ('D') in the 'date'
# column.
data = cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz', np_load=True)['price_data']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(6.4, 7), constrained_layout=True)
# common to all three:
for ax in axs:
    ax.plot('date', 'adj_close', data=data)
    # Major ticks every half year, minor ticks every month,
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=(1, 7)))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_ylabel(r'Price [\$]')

# different formats:
ax = axs[0]
ax.set_title('DefaultFormatter', loc='left', y=0.85, x=0.02, fontsize='medium')

ax = axs[1]
ax.set_title('ConciseFormatter', loc='left', y=0.85, x=0.02, fontsize='medium')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))

ax = axs[2]
ax.set_title('Manual DateFormatter', loc='left', y=0.85, x=0.02,
             fontsize='medium')
# Text in the x axis will be displayed in 'YYYY-mm' format.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b'))
# Rotates and right-aligns the x labels so they don't crowd each other.
for label in ax.get_xticklabels(which='major'):
    label.set(rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: As it happens, the simplest form of the ConciseFormatter turned out to be exactly what I was looking for